# OCaml - creating custom types of custom types

Tags: types, constructor, ocaml

if I have the data types identification and person, how do I use them?

```
type identification = Name of string
| SS of int * int;;

type person = Personal_info of identification;;
```

How do I make a person type that has identification? how do I construct a variable with these types in it..?

something like this:

```
person1 = Personal_info (Name = "Cody") (SS = (231,4534));;
val person1 : person = .....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `identification` type specifies *either* a name or a social security number. It looks to me like you want to have both of them. For that you should probably use a record type:

```
type ident = { name: string; ss: int * int }
```

Since your `person` type has just one variant, it is redundant (not to say that it couldn't be useful in some cases).

Here is a value of type `ident`:

```
{ name = "Cody"; ss = (231, 4534) }
```

If you really want to use the `person` type, it would look something like this:

```
type person = PI of ident
```

A value of this type would look like this:

```
PI { name = "Cody"; ss = (231, 4534) }
```

Comment: Thank you again! It seems you are all over these OCaml tags haha.